# 1 to 1 and 0 to many relationship Laravel not working

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am struggling with an eloquent request. Let me explain what I want to do:

I have two models: User and Item

One User can have many Item and one Item belongs to One user.

I wrote the two method for this relation in my models as followed:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

class User extends Model {
    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'items', 'user_id', 'user_people_id');
    }
}
```

I try to access to the items from my controller its user's relation with:

```
public function index()
{
    $items = Item::with('user')->get();
    dd($items);
```

FYI: I seeded my items table with 10 items and my user table with 4 users:
items table:

[image: items table]

users table:

[image: users table]

My problem is that in the when I check my query with `dd()` here is what I get: Only the 4 first items get the relation, the others 6 return a `null` value

Relation working:

[image: Second item]

Relation returning null:

[image: Fourth item]

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: can you show user table schema

Comment: (What is a “0 to many relationship” supposed to be …?)

Comment: `'user_id'` ??? There is no column `'user_id'` in any of your tables. And you might also need to add your custom column names to the `belongsTo(User::class)` relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Laravel doc, hasMany relationship parameters are the following:

```
return $this->hasMany(Myclass::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

So try to change your relationship in your User class like that

```
// change this
return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'items', 'user_id', 'user_people_id');
// to this
return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'user_people_id', 'id');
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to rename your foreign key to `user_id`. That is what Laravel expects, so you won't need to deal with extra arguments in your `hasMany()` functions.

If you can't do that I think this'll work: `return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'user_people_id');`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add **all** in your query to see if it will work:

**Update**

```php
public function index()
{
    $items = Item::all();
    dd($items);
}
```

Comment: It's either `get()` _or_ `all()`, not both

Comment: Hello iruoy! Thank you, you are right the foreign key was the problem I should have user "user_id".

Comment: You marked the wrong answer as correct then ;)

I would have expected a Foreign Keys section [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), but unfortunately there isn't one.

Laravel expects foreign keys to look like this: tablename_id. If you name all your foreign keys like that Laravel will understand your relations without you having to tell it the foreign key.